# If I remove an S3 lifecycle rule that moves items to Glacier, will it move all the Glacier items out of Glacier immediately?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket that moves old versions into Glacier after 360 days. I would like to remove this rule, but I am afraid it will pull all the old items out of Glacier and into STANDARD storage. If it does this, I would get hit with a lot of charges for the items that have not been in there 90 days and the transfer back.

In short, if I change an S3 to-Glacier lifecycle rule, either shortening the days or removing it, what happens to existing items in Glacier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing will happen to the items in Glacier as there isn't an "undo" type of functionality.  If you remove the rule then nothing will move from S3 to Glacier.  If you shorten it then there may be a little delay until everything is pushed over but they will get pushed to Glacier on the new schedule.

Comment: Is it the same for expired objects?